# Motion with MJPEG format in OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, camera, motion

Right now my router implemented by OpenWRT. The router has motion and webcam for IP cam. 
But when I activated motion, the following error message appears:

```
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
[1] [CRT] [VID] mjpegtoyuv420p: Corrupt image ... continue
```

My webcam is a Logitech c270, and I believe it supports the MJPEG format.

```
v4l2_palette 8
```

which it tells the router to use MJPEG for the webcam.

I followed this website to solve the problem, but I can't find the file that suppose to be edited (file:common_video.c perhaps?).

https://github.com/Mr-Dave/motion/issues/65